# How to read values from table component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have an component called `list` where i will choose some `objects(i,e customers)` from the **dropdown(select with checkbox component)** and i will emit those `selected object(customers)` to another component called **display**, In the **display** component i will show the emitted objects `properties(i,e name,email..etc)` in the table as in below image:

[image]

- Now on clicking **SAVE** button in `display` component, I want to read the values displayed on the `table`.
- When i hit the `SAVE` button, I am calling an function called `onSave` , Inside the `onSave` function i have property called `addCustomer` I want to store values from the table to that property.

How can read values from the table?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-hhsj2n?file=src/app/display/display.component.html)**

Comment: Do you want add selected customer in table?

Comment: I want add all `customers from the table`, **which i previously added from `list `component**.

Comment: Onclicking `SAVE` button.I don't want to perform `POST` operation, I just want to read from the value from table and assign it to `addCustomer` property.

Comment: in `Onsave()` use :`this.addCustomer =this.selectedCustomers;`

Comment: check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-3bckp7

Comment: I got it, thank you @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Ok, let me know for further help if required!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188787/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `this.selectedCustomers` to `this.addCustomer` property like:

```
this.addCustomer = this.selectedCustomers;
```

and if you want to get the id only from the list then you can use:

```
var arr = this.addCustomer.CustomerIds.map(obj => obj.id); // ["1","2"]
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-fadjev)